# Order items with the django-admin interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

Lets say I have a django model looking like this:

```
class question(models.Model):
  order = models.IntegerField('Position')
  question = models.CharField(max_length= 400)
  answer = models.TextField()
  published = models.BooleanField()

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question
```

In my view I show all of the questions ordered ascending by the order field.

My question is: Is there an easy way to edit the order field in the django admin interface? Right now, I have to go to edit the Question, then look up what number to put in the order field and maybe even reorder all the other items. What i really want would be some "up and down"-arrows on the admin page where all the questions are listed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, here is an example of admin.py file with up and down links to change items order:
https://github.com/alexvasi/django-simplemenu/blob/master/simplemenu/admin.py

Basically, you just need to override [get_urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) method to add your custom views (`move_up` and `move_down` in this example).

More famous example would be [django-treemenus](http://code.google.com/p/django-treemenus/), but there is some extra code to support older versions of django.

Answer (score 12):

Check this: [django-orderedmodel](https://github.com/kirelagin/django-orderedmodel).

This is a really simple implementation of abstract base class for items which can be ordered with admin interface. No external dependencies and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**django-admin-sortable2**](https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2) to easily change the order of items including inline items as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable

Comment: Sorry you might have misunderstood me. I want to change the value in the "order" field so that my view can show the items in the order I specified by doing so. With the options you outlined, I can only modify how the elements are shown in the admin view, can't I?

Comment: You're right - I've update my answer. Still, I don't think that you can easily reorder items on-the-fly, as you edit them - you still need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is seeking the solution for that issue in 2017, I found the great package [Django Admin Sortable](https://github.com/alsoicode/django-admin-sortable)