# django admin custom order for foreign key objects

Tags: python, django

I have models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Variant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='variants', null=True)
    stuff = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

admin.py:

```
class VariantInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Variant

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [VariantInline]
    list_display = ['name']
```

Is it possible to **change order of variants in product's admin**? I searched in google but found apps only for ordering whole model, not inlines. [Order items with the django-admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744659/order-items-with-the-django-admin-interface/4745513#4745513)

EDITED: I need possibility to insert variants. For example, lets say in Product i have 10 variants. Then i have to insert one in middle of them. This is what i need.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options) you should be able to use ordering:

```
class VariantInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Variant
    ordering = ("stuff",)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I need custom ordering, which means not by some key, like "stuff". Lets say i have 10 variants and i want insert one in the middle of them. This is what i need.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? There needs to be a field or some piece of logic that contains the ordering information.